# Improper integral: is it convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Is this integral finite?
$$\int_s^t \frac{dx}{x^{1/2} - s^{1/2}}$$
where $s,t \in (0,\infty)$. More generally, I have the following integral
$$\int_s^t \frac{dx}{\left(x^{2\beta}-s^{2\beta}\right)^{k/2}}$$
where $k\geq 1$ is a fixed integer and $\beta \in (0,1/k)$. I wonder if the integral is finite. If not, can one adjust $\beta$ even more to make it finite?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: 
$$\int_{s}^t \frac{1}{x^{1/2}-s^{1/2}} dx=  \int_{s}^t \frac{x^{1/2}+s^{1/2}}{x-s}dx, $$
now substitute $y=x-s$ you get
$$\int_0^{t-s} \frac{x^{1/2}+s^{1/2}}{y}dy\geq \int_0^{t-s} \frac{2s^{1/2}}{y}dy \ldots$$

Comment: and hence $\int_s^t \frac{1}{x^{\beta}-s^{\beta}}dx =\infty$ no matter how small we choose $\beta$, because we can iterate your argument.. I see.. Thanks a lot!!